# Continuity in the conjugacy between Gauss map and Shift.

Tags: dynamical-systems, continued-fractions

Let $\sigma:\Sigma\rightarrow \Sigma$ be the shift map on the space $\Sigma=\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}_+$ of sequences $a=(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{N}_+=\mathbb{N}\backslash \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$ positive integers. Let $X=[0,1]\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ and consider the map $\psi:\Sigma\rightarrow X$ given by
$$\psi(a)=[a_0,a_1,\ldots]=\dfrac{1}{a_0+\dfrac{1}{a_1+\ldots}}.$$

The goal in this problem is to prove that $\psi$ is a conjugacy between the Gauss map $G : X\rightarrow X$ and the shift $\sigma:\Sigma\rightarrow \Sigma$.

Im in trouble in the part when I want to prove that $\psi$ and its inverse $\psi^{-1}$ are continuous. Can someone help please. Thank you

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ normed?

Comment: yes it is normed

Comment: What is the norm on $\Sigma$? The $\ell^1$ norm?

Comment: If $x=(x_0,x_1,\ldots)$. In $\Sigma$ we consider the topology defined by the metric $d(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 2^{-i}d(x_i,y_i)$, where $d(x_i,y_i)=1$ if $x_i\neq y_i$ and $d(x_i,x_i)=0.$

Comment: As usual: you should consider the cylinder sets, nothing else is needed.